# Unsupported type when building a System.Serializable class

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

When turning one of my specific class to a `[System.Serializable]`, Unity suddenly throws me this error, without stacktrace, preventing me to build.

```
Unsupported type MyEnemy
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at ?)
```

I do need this class to be serialized but I can't because of this.

Some similar questions talked about re-attaching the component to fix the issue but my class isn't a component. (Doesn't inherit from `MonoBehaviour`)

I did try this but without success:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
[System.Serializable]
#endif
```

*Should I report this bug to Unity itself directly?*

**EDIT:** As per requested:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class MyEnemy
{
    // Whatever I put in here, even if all [NonSerialized].
}
```

What is odd is that I have other `[System.Serializable]` classes working just fine and I can't figure out what is different with this one.

Both (the working one and the non working one) are used:

- As public/private member of other classes
- As a `List<MyEnemy>`
- As a `Dictionary<key, MyEnemy>`

Any ideas? I'll keep looking and will update this post.

**EDIT 2:** Oh also, it raises precisely 4 times. Which might be a lead? On build and scene saving.

**EDIT 3:** Found this extra line in the editor log.

```
(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor/Src/Prefabs/PropertyModification.cpp Line: 118)
```

Considering reporting this to Unity.

Comment: could you attach your serializable class?

Comment: @Lotan no as you can only attach if your class inherits `MonoBehaviour`. But I'd like to set it as serializable to I can embed it in a component (or ScriptableObject) and edit it there.

Comment: I think he means post the code of that class in your question

Comment: @JeromeJ Yes, I was asking for the code ^^

Comment: As 1) I can't disclose it 2) I don't think it's relevant to the issue 3) I have other classes using System.Serializable working just fine but I can't tell why this one acts differently. Would you have any clues to help me figure this one out? Could it be my architecture?

Comment: You don't have to post your entire code, just the serialized fields

Comment: and the name of the class otherwise this question doesn't have MCVE in order to be answered

Comment: @Programmer it's a custom class inheriting from nothing, I'll include it in my edit.

Comment: why isnt your class public?

Comment: @zambari it is, my bad.

Comment: what about those other classes? are those all public, serializable, and contain valid fields?

Comment: @Bijan Yes, exact same setup. I'm a lill lost.

Comment: I found another example where serialization fails in unity. see my answer again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same behaviour, in my case, simply restarting the editor seemed to do the trick. I had an array in my class that previously was an int, but then I created a struct to hold it, and Unity started complaining, but I think it was just some internal bug in Unity that went away after restarting the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude unwanted fields by adding `[NonSerialized]` attribute.

Some classes and structs can't be serialized such as `Vector` and its derivatives.

Another example is the instances of the following classes which are basically the same:

Instance of a generic class can't be serialized:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo<T> { public List<T> stuff; }
```

Instance of this class can:

```
[Serializable]
public class FooInt : Foo<int> { }
```

serialized attributes may not work on a non-auto-implemented property

---

Generally, serialization in unity with binary formatter isn't the best idea. one reason is backward-compatibility. You can store the data as plain text or JSON.

[Here](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/object-management/persisting-objects/) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) you can find tutorials for save and load in Unity.

Comment: Sadly, even if I put all fields as `[NonSerialized]`, the error still raises.

Comment: @JeromeJ I updated my answer, however if you managed to narrow down your problem and post some more useful info you might get a better answer

Comment: I need it serializable so it can be edited directly in Unity. I used dirty workarounds for now but I'd like figuring out why this one, among all, fail without giving much clues. (Edited my question too)

Comment: @JeromeJ I think you better try replacing `List<MyEnemy>` with a new type `MyEnemyList : List<MyEnemy>`, same for dictionary. I'm not sure if that's the case but..

Comment: Same. Sadly. :( Weren't using `List<MyEnemy>` or `Dictionary<int, MyEnemy>` directly anymore but inheriting it as per suggested.

Comment: @JeromeJ did you use auto-implement properties or public members? serialized attributes may not work on a non-auto-implemented property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172081/discussion-between-jeromej-and-bijan).